Error con clase C++ y pybind11
Estoy usando pybind11 para usar desde python una libreria de la que solo cuento con los headers.
Ya he generado un fichero wrapper en c++ con todas as estructuras y funciones, pero hay una estructura que me da error al compilar cuando la incluyo.
En el header de la librería tengo
/**
 * @class reg
 * @brief Estructura que almacena información a registrar
 */
struct reg {
    std::string v1;
    unsigned char v2;
    unsigned int v3;
    int v4;
    time_t v5;
    std::string v6;
    unsigned char v7;
    unsigned char v8;
    unsigned char v9;
    std::string v10;
    unsigned char v11;
    unsigned char v12;
    std::string v13;
    unsigned char v14;
    bool v15;
    bool v16;
    std::string v17;
};

En el wrapper que estoy intentando compilar tengo
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/chrono.h>
#include "header.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";
    
py::class_<reg>(m, "reg")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("v1", &reg::v1)
    .def_readwrite("v2", &reg::v2)
    .def_readwrite("v3", &reg::v3)
    .def_readwrite("v4", &reg::v4)
    .def_readwrite("v5", &reg::v5)
    .def_readwrite("v6", &reg::v6)
    .def_readwrite("v7", &reg::v7)
    .def_readwrite("v8", &reg::v8)
    .def_readwrite("v9", &reg::v9)
    .def_readwrite("v10", &reg::v10)
    .def_readwrite("v11", &reg::v11)
    .def_readwrite("v12", &reg::v12)
    .def_readwrite("v13", &reg::v13)
    .def_readwrite("v14", &reg::v14)
    .def_readwrite("v15", &reg::v15)
    .def_readwrite("v16", &reg::v16)
    .def_readwrite("v17", &reg::v17);

Compilo con la siguiente instruccion
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) -I . example.cpp -o example$(python3-config --extension-suffix) -L. -llibreria -Wl,-rpath,.

Y el error al intentar compilar es el siguiente
example.cpp: In function ‘void pybind11_init_example(pybind11::module&)’:
example.cpp:211:24: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class type_, class ... options> class pybind11::class_’
     py::class_<reg>(m, "reg")

Tengo mas estructuras y clases vinculadas sin problema pon pybind11, pero cuando añado esta clase reg me da error en la compilacion

El único error que obtengo es redeclaration of 'unsigned char reg::v8'. Corrigiendo eso no obtengo ningún otro error

@Mateo ¿es posible que la programación de la libreria tenga definido un template o algo similar que ocasiona el error? Todo lo que he encontrado relativo a ese mensaje del compilador es por el uso de un template. Pero desconozco si puede estar dentro de la libreria y no en el header

en el header revisaste que este la definicion v8? o v9

@Bryro si, ha sido un error al transcribirlo al crear la pregunta. Me pregunto si será algo no visible en el header que está contenido en la propia libreria

Con este código también tienes problemas? https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/docs%2Fclasses.rst

Por si a caso prueba convirtiendo el struct en clase.

gracias @Mateo por tu ayuda. He publicado mi propia respuesta ya que he localizado el problema

El error al compilar se debía a que existía en los header de la librería una definición de un enum donde uno de los valores tenía el mismo nombre reg que la clase.
enum tipo_fichero{
    est = 0,
    val = 1,
    reg = 2
};

Lo he solucionado cambiando en el header por:
enum tipo_fichero{
   est = 0,
   val = 1,
   reg2 = 2
};

y en su bind correspondiente por:
py::enum_<enum tipo_fichero>(m, "tipo_fichero")
    .value("est", est)
    .value("val", val)
    .value("reg2", reg2)
    .export_values();

Quizás haya una manera mejor de mantener los nombres originales, pero no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo.
